# How to create a jar file from two projects on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

I have two projects in eclipse.  I know how to create a jar file for each project individually, however I want to combine the two jar files again and create another jar from them?  Ideally I would like to script it and automate it.  Any help will be highly appreciated.  If there is any example online, I will appreciate if you could share it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have one project depend on the other, and use the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to build an uber-jar of the second project (thus containing the classes of the first project). You need to use Maven or other build tools for this to work though.

Comment: If I am not wrong, maven-shade-plugin extracts the classes on which the other project is dependent and then make them into one jar.  But I want to have a jar containing other jars.  I found a similar question on stackoverflow and the answer to that was to use Maven One jar plugin.  I tried that but when I build the final project I get error message saying dependencies cannot be resolved.  I googled that and it says that because the respositories are not available.  My problem is that these jars are not from maven repository but my own project.  If you could kindly guide me

Comment: A jar of jars then? I'm curious as to why anyone would need that, but since JAR files are essentially compressed directories, why don't you use 7zip to add your jars in one single archive?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem.  I used the Maven one jar plugin.